# Getting this error when I try to use video feature in WebSocket connection to 'wss://endpoint.twilio.com/' failed:

Tags: javascript, php, video, twilio

I'm using "Programmable Video" product to chat video call in my site using PHP.
When i try to connect with the video, i'm getting WebSocket connection to 'wss://endpoint.twilio.com/' failed: error. How to solve this issue. I am using JavaScript method to connect twilio video: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.20.1/twilio-video.min.js

Why not By using the JavaScript CDN https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.20.1/twilio-video.min.js
The video call feature not working.

In twilio site it says the "Programmable Video" product no longer support. However, it says it will work for existing customers till Dec 2024. Please advise why its not working in my website.
How to solve this issue.

Comment: _"i'm getting WebSocket connection to 'wss://endpoint.twilio.com/' failed: error"_  What is the exact error? Linking us minified Javascript files isn't going to help anyone

Comment: Just an FYI, Twilio Programmable Video is no longer supported, and will end of life on December 5th, 2024. The [official migration path](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/programmable-video-eol-notice) is to migrate to [Zoom Video SDK](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/video-sdk/twilio/). We are happy to support your use case.